# Line 149, Column 31: there is no attribute "WIDTH"

Tags: w3c-validation

All my site WC3 happy - except [one page](http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/gallery.php) with three small notes ...
On this page I embedded Slider that somehow causes this message:

```
Line 149, Column 31: there is no attribute "WIDTH"
<a href="images2/1.jpg" width="1280" height="960" border="0">
```

Maybe it is because the slide is not supported fully on my site?

In addition, even though I gave `height/width` settings to all photos,
I got a note (`website load time testing`) give all these settings pictures ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple validation message. Cause DOCTYPE (`HTML 4.01 Transitional`) you are using deprecates visual formating html attributes like `width`, `height`, `border` etc. You can use `CSS-properties` instead or ignore this if it these attributes are set by a some `<script>`, e.g. your slider, there will be nothing dangerous. CSS is:

```
img {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 960px;
    border: none;
}
```

`website load time testing` is, as I can suppose, a message from your developing tool. I think it is normal. Except one point: your site for some reason is very slow to load, so the message refers to that issue. When a page loads fast you simply do not have time to spot it.

Comment: thenks...! O.K 100%
I only have one problem with CSS file
#content-side .banner Property _height doesn't exist : 118px
#banner2  Property _height doesn't exist : 118px
#content-main  Property _height doesn't exist : 320px

I do not know what they want?

If I take off the mark  _
This confirms that it was okay - but the site itself function does not work right ...